# Open Text file from Oracle Forms Prompt

Tags: database, oracle, file, plsql, oracleforms

I am using Oracle Forms and I would like to open a log file (text file) from a prompt. The prompt will ask if the user would like to open the text file and clicking yes would open it. Any recommendations?

Comment: What Oracle forms do you use? If you use 9i or above, from where do you want to open file client or host?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The solution was found successfully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to open the text file using the following by providing the full file path with the file name:

```
x_host('viewfile_nowait',w_filepath);
```